# Google Login with Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-signin

In my website I have a candidate account and a Employer account.

I want to add google login for both users. Both have different controller methods and routes.

Google login for candidate is working but google login with employer saying redirect URI mismatch.

In my google console I have add two redirect URI's one for candidate and one for employer.

My question is is it possible to have multiple redirect uri in `.env`

My `.env` looks like
:

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=
GOOGLE_URL=http://www.theunitedjobs.com/login/jobseeker/google/callback
```

But I want to add two google_url want to add this also 
:

```
GOOGLE_URL=http://theunitedjobs.com/login/employer/google/callback
```

So is it possible to add two redirect URI's???

Comment: It's not possible.  Use `GOOGLE_URL_EMPLOYEE`.

Comment: but in services.php how these two can be fetched    my services.php looks           'google' => [
   'client_id'     => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
   'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
   'redirect'      => env('GOOGLE_URL'),
  ],

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a login_uri parameter for your google login markup , you can use [data-callback](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-callback) and check in the function on which route you want to send the route to.

Comment: What is the question/problem exactly you are trying to resolve?

Comment: i was solving the problem mentioned above with regards to having an option to use different routes based on different URLs.